# UIPopoverPresentationController/UIPopoverController loses backgroundColor on interface rotation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller, popover, presentviewcontroller

I've got a menu in iOS that I'm displaying in a popover. I can present a popover in both iOS7 and iOs8 using UIPopoverController and UIPopoverPresentation controllers respectively. I'm running into a problem though that when the popover is visible and the device rotates, the popover disappears for a split second during the animation, then it reappears after the animation. The problem is, when the popover reappears, its background color is drawn as the default background color.

I'm setting the color by using the `backgroundColor` property.

```
self.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; // iOS 8 style
```

I'm 90% sure this is actually a bug in Apple's implementation. The value I see in the `backgroundColor` after rotation property is correct, but the pixels drawn are not. I wonder if anybody else has experienced this issue and found work arounds. If there is a radar open I'll follow it, if not I'll submit one myself.

I'll add how I am presenting the popover. In both versions I use a barButtonItem as my anchor.

```
[self.menuPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:item permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:animated];
```

Here it is using the new iOS8 UIPresentationPopoverController:

```
UIPopoverPresentationController *popover = self.popoverPresentationController;
popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
popover.barButtonItem = item;
[viewController presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];  // I'm presenting a view controller from within itself.
```

Comment: It looks like there is a `_UIPopoverViewBackgroundComponentView` that is being reallocated when the rotation occurs. When this reallocation occurs, I guess the color is not set to the value in the popover's 'backgroundColor' property. It seems the issue only occurs when memory is strained because in some scenarios the view is not reallocated and everything looks fine.

Comment: Did you submit a radar or find a workaround for this?

Comment: I haven't submitted a radar for this as when I created a sample project to test the behavior I was unable to reproduce. I'm guessing its because my actual application consumes more data than a blank view so the memory is never released/reallocated. I was able to find a work around, that was to follow the tutorial below and create a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView subclass. My designers just copied the look and feel of the iOS 8 popover for as close as possible assets.  http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/customizing-the-design-of-uipopovercontroller

Comment: Thanks. I am only seeing it intermittently. I will check out that blog

Comment: Definitely a bug. Here is my bug report: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5810000702210048. Please dup it .

Comment: It's now being fixed in iOS 10, anyone knows a workaround for iOS 9?